# Passing subset of constant values to angular component

Tags: angular, object, constants, subset

I have the following constant defined in one of my models.

```
    export const NEWS_TYPE_TEXT = {
      News: 'News',
      Interview: 'Interview',
      Digest: 'Digest',
      CompanyAnalysis: 'Company Analysis',
    };
```

Usually I would pass the whole constant to the component, i.e.:

```
<mb-simple-select [options]="NEWS_TYPE_TEXT"> </mb-simple-select>
```

But now I need to pass only a subset of these values.
(For example, only 'News' and 'Digest').

I have tried the following, which does not work:

```
<simple-select [options]="NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.News, NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.Digest"></simple-select>
```

Then I tried the following. This works, but passes the values as an array, and only the actual text values, without the keys:

```
<simple-select [options]="[NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.News, NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.Digest]"></simple-select>
```

Is there an elegant way to pass this subset of values to a component so that they preserve their object key:value structure?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
<simple-select [options]="{News: NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.News, Digest: NEWS_TYPE_TEXT.Digest}"></simple-select>
```

Comment: I tried that one too, unfortunately it throws a syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: Yes that worked! 
A simple solution, thank you.
Though it does mean you have to manually enter the keys yourself when passing it in. 
I suppose there's no way to elegantly do it with a single value.

Comment: Another way to do it would be with a map on your object entries in your ts, I guess. But this way is the easiest!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you define class for the required options and pass it.

i.e:

1. Define class X for News, Digest
2. Assign the values of X inside the ts
3. Define @Input() to support X inside simple-select
4. Pass the X to simple-select

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a direct answer to the issue. You might have to create a quick pipe to produce an object containing only the properties you wish to have.

Try the following

**pluck.pipe.ts**

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: "pluck", pure: true })
export class PluckPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: {[key: string]: string}, args?: Array<string>): any {
    if (!value) return null;

    return args.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr] = value[curr];
      return acc;
    }, Object.create(null));
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```html
<simple-select [options]="NEWS_TYPE_TEXT | pluck:['News','Digest']"></simple-select>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wzzfkq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

<sup>Pipe namesake is the RxJS [`pluck`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/pluck) operator. Other than the name, it's completely unrelated to the issue at hand.</sup>

Comment: Interesting solution, thank you. Perhaps a little overengineered for our purpose, which implies that we may be better off refactoring how we've structured our constants. But may give this a go a bit later. Thanks again.